# Does LGPL allow closed-source third party modules?

Tags: lgpl

I wonder if i could, for example, distribute a commercial, closed source module for the Qt framework, that is licensed under LGPL.

Does LGPL allow closed source third party modules that may make use of components of the framework itself (like algorithms or data structures, data types etc)?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLPlugins and the immediately following questions in the GPL FAQ? Is your closed-source module establishing 'intimate communication' or not?

Comment: I did not refer in particular to plugins, but rather a Qt module, that would be like a library providing new classes and functionalities. An example would be QtWebEngine, that is a module wrapping webengine to provide widgets and other related wrappers to a web engine view.
Another examples could be https://github.com/KDAB/KDDockWidgets , that provides a dock widget into which to dock regular QWidgets provided by the framework or by other modules.
So in this sense it is something that needs to be linked to the application, at least when not restricting oneself to QML plugins that are plugins

Comment: Is your code a dependency of the LGPL-licensed software, or is it the other way around? It would be helpful if you explained your case for people that are not experts on the QT framework.